# Keeping a counter in model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to create a poll/voting application and want to keep track of the amount of votes that are made for the options. When a vote is made, an id is passed in and depending on the id - the counter is increased by one. But when I vote it sets the other counter back to one.

```
    // ID of the option selected:
    public int VotedID { get; set; }

    Counters for the options:
    public int BlueCornerPercent { get; set; }
    public int RedCornerPercent { get; set; }


    // Snippet of code - here is where I increase the counters. theFight is an instance of the model/entity.
    public void HandleVotes(Fight fight)
    {

        // Get full fight details:
        Fight theFight = db.Fights.Find(fight.FightId);

        // Get fighters id's in fight:
        var f1 = (from l in theFight.Fighters
                  select l).First();

        var f2 = (from l in theFight.Fighters
                  select l).Last();

        if (theFight.VotedID == f1.FighterID)
        {
            theFight.BlueCornerPercent++;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        else if (theFight.VotedID == f2.FighterID)
        {
            theFight.RedCornerPercent++;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

As seen I'm passing in the "Fight" that is being voted on and changing the counter from there...

Comment: Are you instantiating a new instance of your class each tie you update it?

Comment: I think I may be actually, hmm.

Comment: The snippets you've posted are insufficient. Please post your entire controller.

Comment: If that is the case then it is going to reset all of your properties each time that it is changed

Comment: I posted the full function, any idea how I would do it to keep the counter from resetting?

Comment: Did you make any adjustments to the fight variable that was passed in to that method?

Comment: You did not disable `AutoDetectChangesEnabled`, did you?

Comment: If the passed in `fight` is attached to the context with the counters = 0 you get 1 as result in the DB. `Find` does not refresh an attached entity with the DB values. Did you check in the debugger what values `theFight.Blue/RedCornerPercent` have after the `Find`? And where does `fight` come from?

Comment: @Slauma But if `db` is the same instance `theFight` will always have the incremented values. If `db` is a new instance `Find` will fetch `theFight` from the database. Robert, what is the life span of `db` and does any refresh happen anywhere, like (as Slauma suggests) for fetching `fight`?

Comment: @GertArnold: I had a scenario in mind like: `var fight = new Fight { FightId = idFromPostAction }; db.Fights.Attach(fight); HandleVotes(fight);` The saved counters would be 1 because `Find` will return `fight` where the counters are not initialized (=0), wouldn't they?

Comment: @Slauma Yes, that's what I figured too after your first comment. Both variables would effectively be the same instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I needed to include hidden attributes for the counters in my view to keep them from resetting.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using something like:

```
    if (theFight.VotedID == f1.FighterID)
    {
        theFight.BlueCornerPercent++;
        db.Entry(theFight).Property(p => p.BlueCornerPercent).IsModified = true;
        db.Entry(theFight).Property(p => p.RedCornerPercent).IsModified = false;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```